# Python: how to find the indices of elements in one list, and their corresponding values in another list

Tags: python-2.7

I kindly need a little direction with this task. Given two different lists with same length, I want to find the indices of elements in one list (B), and their corresponding values in the other list (A). Below is a piece of the code I wrote, but the second part is not working as I expected.

```
A = [2,4,3]
B = [1,1,0]
for b in B:
    index_1 = B.index(b)
    print b, "<--->", index_1

    ##__the following outputs are correct by my expectation:
     #    1 <---> 0
     #    1 <---> 0
     #    0 <---> 2

    ##___Below code is for the second part of my question:
    value_of_index_1_b = A.index(index_1)
    print index_1, "<--->", value_of_index_1_b

 ##-- And, the following was my expected outputs, but I'm not getting these:
       #    0 <---> 2
       #    0 <---> 4
       #    2 <---> 3
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: since you have started learning programming and coding in python language, I highly recommend switching to python 3, support for python 2 ends by the end of next year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use zip function with enumerate

```
for i, (b, a) in enumerate(zip(B, A)):
   index_1 = i
   print b , "<--->", index_1
```

`i` will keep track of the index number in both A, B element-wise together, while zip is used to combine both lists element by element

Here is a worked out example

```
A = [2,4,3]
B = [1,1,0]

for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(A,B)):

    print(i, a, b, A[i]==a, B[i]==b)

0 2 1 True True
1 4 1 True True
2 3 0 True True
```

Answer (score 0):

`A.index(index_1)` returns the *index* of `index_1` in the list `A`, not the `A.index(index_1)`th value of `A`. You should *retrieve* the value at index `index_1` instead:

```
 value_of_index_1_b = A[index_1]
```

Then you should get:

```
#    0 <---> 2
#    0 <---> 2 (not 4)
#    2 <---> 3
```